# How to convert this SIGNAL and SLOT to qt5 connect call?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I want to use the qt5 style of this old-style connect call:

```
connect(socket, SIGNAL(error(QAbstractSocket::SocketError)), this,
    SLOT(erreurSocket(QAbstractSocket::SocketError)));
```

I tried

```
connect(socket, &QTcpSocket::error, this, &FenClient::erreurSocket);
```

without success:

> candidate function not viable: no overload of 'error' matching 'const char*' for 2nd argument

FenClient.cpp

```
FenClient::FenClient()
{
    setupUi(this);

    socket = new QTcpSocket(this);
    connect(socket, &QTcpSocket::error, this, &FenClient::erreurSocket);
```

FenClient.h

```
private slots:
    void erreurSocket(QAbstractSocket::SocketError erreur);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractsocket.html#error-1):

> Note: Signal error is overloaded in this class. To connect to this
>   signal by using the function pointer syntax, Qt provides a convenient
>   helper for obtaining the function pointer as shown in this example:
>
> ```
> connect(abstractSocket, QOverload<QAbstractSocket::SocketError>::of(&QAbstractSocket::error),
>     [=](QAbstractSocket::SocketError socketError){ /* ... */ });
> ```

So in your case the solution is:

```cpp
connect(socket, QOverload<QAbstractSocket::SocketError>::of(&QAbstractSocket::error), this, &FenClient::erreurSocket);
```

Comment: Adding to this, QOverload was added in Qt 5.7.  Earlier versions of Qt 5 need a static_cast as shown [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots-syntaxes.html#selecting-overloaded-signals-and-slots) to select between overloaded signals/slots.